# IndexError: too many indices on Python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pydev, osx-mountain-lion, kaggle

Using PyDev with an eclipse environment for Python 2.7 on OSX. Trying to count the element in the array and sum up the elements in the array. Getting an error on the index.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import sys

csv_file_object = fileName = os.path.join('train.csv')
print('Directory separator on your platform ({}): {}'.format(sys.platform, os.sep))

data=[]
for row in csv_file_object:
    data.append(row)
data = np.array(data)

number_passengers = np.size(data[0::,0].astype(np.float))
number_survived = np.sum(data[0::,0].astype(np.float))
proportion_survivors = number_survived / number_passengers

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/scdavis6/Documents/Kaggle/Titanic1.py", line 14, in <module>
    number_passengers = np.size(data[0::,0].astype(np.float))
IndexError: too many indices
```

Let me know if I can provide additional information.

Thank you.

---

**Update:** 
I made [the edits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21182098/1639625), but got another error about the module not being callable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/scdavis6/Documents/Kaggle/Titanic1.py", line 5, in <module>
    csv_file_object = fileName = os.path('train.csv')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

---

**Update:**
I changed os.path('train.csv') to os.path.join('train.csv'), but got another error about not finding the .csv file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/scdavis6/Documents/Kaggle/Titanic1.py", line 9, in <module>
    with open(fileName) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'train.csv'
```

Here's the absolute path for the .csv file and the python scripts.

```
import os
os.path.abspath("/Users/scdavis6/Desktop/train.csv")
```

'/Users/scdavis6/Desktop/train.csv'

```
import os
os.path.abspath("/Users/scdavis6/Documents/Kaggle/Titanic1.py")
```

'/Users/scdavis6/Documents/Kaggle/Titanic1.py'

Comment: What is the shape of data after converting it to a np.array? (print data.shape)

Comment: @Mailerdaimon the print data.shape command gives: Directory separator on your platform (darwin): / (9,)

Comment: @ScottDavis Have a look at my answer below. I think you do not read the file at all, but instead just split up the file name, resulting in a 1d array, for which those complex numpy indices make no sense.

Comment: @tobias_k I made the edits, but got another error about the module not being callable.

Comment: Because (according to the error) you changed `os.path.join('train.csv')` to `os.path('train.csv')`. Also, please don't completely substitute the code in your question, but add an updated version below that, otherwise the answers will look awkward.

Comment: @tobias_k I cannot find the updated button, nor information about that option on the stackoverflow site. Also, after putting in .join, I got a new error:  File "/Users/scdavis6/Documents/Kaggle/Titanic1.py", line 9, in <module>
    with open(fileName) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'train.csv'

Comment: What "updated button"? "Updating" your question is the same as "editing", which you seem to know already, just don't replace all the code, or else an answer that explains the (now non-existent) bug in the original code will seem stupid and might even get downvoted by others. About the new error: If you want that fixed, add the absolute paths of both your script and the `csv` file to your question.

Comment: @tobias_k thanks for clarifying the update process. Included the error as well as the absolute path for the .csv and .py files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is your actual code, the problem is that you never open the file. Your `csv_file_object` is still just the `fileName`, and thus your `data` is made up of the characters of that file name, resulting in a 1D numpy array.

Instead, you should `open` the file and create a `csv.reader` for it.

```
import csv
with open(fileName) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data=[]
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
    data = np.array(data)
```

Or shorter: `data = np.array([row for row in csv.reader(f)])`

---

**Update:** The new error you are getting is probably due to you accidentally changing 
`os.path.join('train.csv')` to `os.path('train.csv')`, i.e., instead of calling the `join` function from the `os.path` module, you are (trying to) call the module itself.

---

**Update:** It seems your `train.csv` file is not in the same directory as your Python script, thus the script won't find the file if you just use the filename. You have to use the absolute path together with the filename:

```
fileName = os.path.join('/Users/scdavis6/Desktop', 'train.csv')
```

Or just `fileName = '/Users/scdavis6/Desktop/train.csv'`. Alternatively, move your `train.csv` file to the same directory as your Python script. This might indeed be the better and more robust option, unless you are using this file in multiple scripts in different directories.